# MathJax React native issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, math, mathjax

**It Shows**
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Error]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
and for some math's shows
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnerW.png)
and with the inline math's issue , can we somehow break line

i tried the  css flexbox in react native for line break ,but not working, and for the object error i tried several methods but the maths latex when gets curly braces it executes as code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.